# Apache Tomcat 6 keeps the old application URI

Tags: url, web-applications, uri, tomcat6, spring-3

I know, this is a very noob question but it is really affecting my productivity.

I'm developing a Spring 3 Web Aplication with STS 2.8.

When I change the RequestMapping value (the URIs I map my controller's methods to) and I run the modified application on apache tomcat 6... it keeps the old URI as they were never changed.

I tried a lot of workarounds: clean, clean working directory, removing the runtime environment and recreate it, but nothing affects tomcat behaviour.
It still maps the old URI to the controller's methods and the new ones resolve to a 404.

What am I missing?

Comment: are you running your tomcat through eclipse? (it sounds that way from your references to "clean" and "clean working directory")

Comment: great! it makes you look more credible when you ask questions. so, do you know where your tomcat executes? are you aware of how the folder structure looks?

Comment: I hope not to misunderstand you question... well, I think I execute apache from my installation running from the File System path I put it into C:Java/Program Files/Apache Foundation/Apache6/ecc...
However it uses the workspace metadata and folder to deploy the appliaction. This is the way I figured the things out. Maybe I'm making a poor showing of myself... :(

Comment: right, under metadata! look at the folder tmp0 (or some other number, depending on how many servers you've set up in the eclipse workspace you're in. two questions now: how many tmp folders do you find? and can you find your web project where you're having problems?

Comment: this wack-a-tomcat is getting exciting! XD
I can see 3 folders: "publish" with 3 ".dat" files, "tmp0" with a "publish.txt" file and finally "tmp1" with the tomcat hierarchy and  my application folder too. So, yes, I can find my web project where I'm having problems.

Comment: hehe :) ok, so this is then your second server in this eclipse workspace. now, under your project folder, there should be a folder named web-inf. and in that folder, there should be a web.xml. read that file (in notepad++ preferably). does it look the way it should?

Comment: mmm actually yes. It is exactly the way it should. And to be honest now I'm wondering if I'm not messing with the RequestMapping annotations (which are behaving a little weirdly). Just to know, does tomcat cache the deploied applications? And what is the command to get en effective web app update? An I doing something bad using tomcat under eclipse? It'd be better doing something different? Thank you so much for you time.

Comment: tomcat under eclipse is fine. i don't know about spring request mapping annotations :( tomcat doesn't cache beyond a restart, except for the session. restarting your browser clears that (try it). perhaps spring caches more..

Comment: ok, let me make a summary, just to clarify the things:

1) tomcat doesn't cache anything (but the session) that endures a restart
2) we have to remember that the browser has a cache too (yes, reaaaally 4 dummies ;-) )

so if we want a CLEAN restart we have to close the browser and restart tomcat. if the things aren't allright we must find a solution elsewhere.

Just a last little OT question: what are the "clean" options for? To turn tomcat in the "newly installed" state?

Comment: haha :D the "clean" options are mainly there for those occasions when eclipse makes mistakes. it redeploys everything. i'm really sorry, i'm not gonna be able to help :C

Comment: You are wrong, you helped me alot!!!
First, now I know exactly what tomcat does (the suspects are the programmer worse nightmares!), second the things are starting to work (it is very common to me looking for errors in a place while they hide somewhere else). For example I had a little troubles with the web.xml url-pattern param set to "/*". And finally I am very grateful to people like you who share their knoledge with the inexperienced programmers. So I thank you very much again.